# Outline Numbering for Mathematica Section/Subsection Cells

Tags: formatting

I am trying to create a LaTex-style document with Section numbers of the form 1.0 and then subsection numbers 1.1, 2.1, etc. I need the numbering to be automatic such that if I insert a new subsection, the numbering of subsequent subsections will automatically adjust. Is there an easy way to do this (presumably by editing the stylesheet??). I've looked at a bunch of options but can't seem to find the appropriate one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996938/how-to-fill-in-cellframelabels-in-mathematica-notebook-styles) might help.

In short, to get an automatically numbered section or subsection you could edit the `CellFrameLabels` or the `CellDingbat` option of the relevant style definitions.

- Open a new notebook, add a section cell, and select `Edit Stylesheet...` in the Format menu
- Choose `Section` from the drop down menu in the stylesheet editor and select the newly created cell
- Check `Show Expression` in the Cell menu which
- Add either the option `CellFrameLabels-> {{spec, None}, {None, None}}` or `CellDingbat -> spec` somewhere after the first argument where `spec` is the specifications for the section number.
- Uncheck `Show Expression`. Sections in the should then be numbered automatically
- You can install the updated stylesheet by pressing the `Install Stylesheet...` button in the stylesheet editor

In its simplest form the number specification would be something like

```
 Cell[TextData[{ CounterBox["Section"]}]]
```

for a section or

```
Cell[TextData[{ CounterBox["Section"], ".", CounterBox["Subsection"]}]]
```

for a subsection, but you can add your own styling to the numbering. For example for a notebook using the default stylesheet you could set the style definition of `Section` to something like

```
Cell[StyleData["Section"],
  CellFrameLabels->{{
    Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Section"], " "}],
    CellFrame -> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}}, 
    CellFrameMargins -> 4, 
    CellSize -> {30, Automatic}, 
    TextAlignment -> Right], 
   None}, {None, None}},
  CellFrameLabelMargins->0
]
```

Which would produce sections like this

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ah, very nice. Your example worked very well. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can add automatic numbering using `Insert | Automatic numbering...`. The menu is pretty self-explanatory; to have a numbering that resets with every new "`Alt+4`" headline, select `Section` as counter. To have something like `Section.Subsection`, you'll have to use that menu twice, and then put the dot between the numbers manually.

I do not know how to automatically do this via the stylesheet, so unfortunately I'm limited to doing this every time I create a new headline. You can however copy+paste the automatic numbering, replace the actual caption in the new place, and you'll have just what you want.

Comment: (+1) this is a way that a lazy guy like me do! :D

Comment: If the text is centered, there is a difference between the CellFrameLabels method and the Insert > Automatic numbering method.  In the former, the number is far left away from the text, in the latter, the number is adjacent to the text.